# How can i variable add new charcter another string?

Tags: php, variables

Hi guy can you help me i have problem sometimes variable.

```
<?php

$ns = "test";
echo $ns;
```

print test but I don't want this.

**output**

> t:e:s:t

please help?

Answer (score 2):

Use [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

chunk_split() function splits the function.

In our case, it splits by every 1 character.

And adds a new character `:`.

We do not need last `:` character so, we are using [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
<?php
$ns = "test";
$n = chunk_split($ns, 1, ':');
echo rtrim($n, ":");
?>
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/wsh96o)

Comment: ok mate i fix thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
$ns = "test";
$array = str_split($ns);
echo implode(":", $array);
```

Comment: Just one this instead of using `try below code :` use proper explanation or provide some link to make your answer better!!

Comment: ok i will take care of this in future. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php $ns = "test";
    echo substr(chunk_split($ns, 1, ':'), 0, -1);
   ?>
```

Comment: You code output is `t:e:s:t:` extra `:` at last

Comment: Now it looking fine!!

Comment: thanks for showing my mistake ..

Comment: Please add proper explanation to your answer to make it better and useful for future user of SO

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php